# View openssl arguments

Tags: openssl, centos, heartbleed-bug

Due to the heartbleed openssl vulnerability , I need to compile openssl  from source.However i would like to know the argument that was passed at `./config` phase so that I can use the same for the latest openssl .

What command should I use to get this detail ?

Do I need to regenerate my SSL cert for my site?

Comment: Running `openssl version -a` generally displays the flags that was used to compile it. So run this on your old version, and use the similar for you current version. Regarding your SSL cert, that's a little out of scope here. There is a lot more going on at serverfault.com discussing Heartbleed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i would like to know the argument that was passed at `./config`

As vcsjones stated (he should have answered), use `openssl version -a` for some (perhaps most?) of them:

```
$ /usr/local/ssl/darwin/bin/openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
built on: Mon Apr 14 11:54:49 EDT 2014
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN 
-DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM 
-DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl/darwin"
```

Some options/arguments you will need to know how they got there. For example, for `-fPIC` and `-DOPENSSL_PIC`, I added `export CFLAGS="-fPIC"` before I compiled.

Others are simply missing. For example, I `config`'d with `no-ssl2`. That's found in `<openssl/opensslconf.h>`:

```
$ cat /usr/local/ssl/darwin/include/openssl/opensslconf.h | grep SSL2
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
# define OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
# if defined(OPENSSL_NO_SSL2) && !defined(NO_SSL2)
#  define NO_SSL2
# endif
```